# Bash script to get nested http response from URL

Tags: bash, https, reverse-proxy

I have a scenario where I am deploying applications to a Tomcat instance using a bash script and need to test if the endpoint (a login screen in this case) is truly available by testing it before I declare the deployment activity as being successful.

There is a wrinkle in the situation, as it were. Tomcat is hiding behind a reverse proxy, so when I test the endpoint it needs to go through the Apache Webserver on HTTPS, get rerouted and then return the response from the actual endpoint desired.

I am currently trying the following:

```
response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null https://url.to.test)
```

However this obviously does not follow the potential 301 presented by the reverse proxy, and simply hands the 301 back as the answer.

My Google-fu must be weak these days because I can't find anyone else who has suffered through the same or a similar enough issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want curl to follow 30x redirects, use `-L` aka `--location`.

Comment: How am I so dumb as to not have seen that option!

The solution is perfectly succinct and helpful. tyvm